# wpf TreeView DataTemplate - replace element with tree

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Given following model

```
class Storage
{
    public List<Stored> StoredItems { get; }
}

class Stored
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<File> Files { get; } = new List<File>();
}

class File
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Tree Schema { get; set; }
}

class Tree
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public List<Tree> Children { get; set; } = new List<Tree>();
}
```

I would like to display `Storage` in `TreeView` as follows:

```
StoredItem1.Name
  File1.Schema.Label
    File1.Schema.Children[0].Label
    File1.Schema.Children[1].Label
      File1.Schema.Children[1].Children.Label
  File2.Schema.Label
StoredItem2.Name
```

i.e. display all `Stored`s that would contain `Schema` of each file, which is recursive.

I am not sure how to achieve it, my main problem is how to get the `Schema` to be displayed. When I changed my model to wrap `Schema` in a singleton list, it started to work but I would like to avoid polluting my model with such thing, also still, I don't want to display file name and instead of file display its schema.

Another thing I would like to have have a property `SelectedStoredItem` in my view model and bind it to, well, selected `Stored` item. It can be null if for example some schema node is selected, or be equal to the `Stored` to which selected node belongs, but I prefer first option.

Here is my xaml, it doesn't do what I want, just displays `Stored` items and their file names.

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Storage/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView
                ItemsSource="{Binding StoredItems}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Stored}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:File}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Schema}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tree}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here is complete code behind

```
namespace TreeViewTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    class Storage
    {
        public Storage()
        {
            StoredItems = new List<Stored>();
            var a1 = new Stored {Name = "Stored1"};
            a1.Files.Add(new File
            {
                Name = "File1",
                Schema = new Tree
                {
                    Label = "1_1",
                    Children = new List<Tree> { new Tree { Label = "1_1_1" } }
                }
            });
            a1.Files.Add(new File
            {
                Name = "File2",
                Schema = new Tree
                {
                    Label = "2_1",
                    Children = new List<Tree> { new Tree { Label = "2_1_1" }, new Tree { Label = "2_1_2" } }
                }
            });

            var a2 = new Stored { Name = "Stored2" };
            a2.Files.Add(new File
            {
                Name = "File1",
                Schema = new Tree
                {
                    Label = "1_1",
                    Children = new List<Tree> { new Tree { Label = "1_1_1" } }
                }
            });

            StoredItems.Add(a1);
            StoredItems.Add(a2);
        }

        public List<Stored> StoredItems { get; }
    }

    class Stored
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<File> Files { get; } = new List<File>();
    }

    class File
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Tree Schema { get; set; }
    }

    class Tree
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public List<Tree> Children { get; set; } = new List<Tree>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to display file name and instead of file display its schema

so change data template for file

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:File}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Schema.Children}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Schema.Label}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

---

side note

```
Children = new List<Tree> { new Tree { Label = "2_1_1" }, new Tree { Label = "2_1_2" } }
```

creating a new List inside object initializer is not necessary here. It has already been initialized (`public List<Tree> Children { get; set; } = new List<Tree>();`) and you can write a [collection-initializer](/questions/tagged/collection-initializer) like this:

```
Children = { new Tree { Label = "2_1_1" }, new Tree { Label = "2_1_2" } }
```

Comment: Damn, this was pretty simple. Regarding the initialization, I initialized list for every object just to be sure that I don't get a null, I don't do this kind of things in real code, just wanted to put up the structure quickly. Still nice too know this syntax sugar. Thank you.